# take list from checkboxes and insert into css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want users to be able to select from a row of check-boxes of additions to make to `CSS`.

I'm using `JS` to search for checked boxes, take the names, put into a list, then take the list and put it into `CSS` as a value for a property.

I can't tell if it's going into the `CSS` just incorrectly, or not going in at all.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  var checkbox = document.querySelector('[type="checkbox"]');

  checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
      getOTFeaturesTextA();
  });
});

function getOTFeaturesTextA(){

  var textA = document.getElementById("textA"),
    chkArray = [];

  $(".ot-textA:checked").each(function() {
    chkArray.push($(this).val());
  });

  var selected;
  selected = chkArray.join(',') ;

  if(selected.length > 0){
    textA.css("font-feature-settings", selected + ", liga"); 
  }else{
    textA.css("font-feature-settings", "liga");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ot-checkboxes">
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frac" value="'frac'" class="ot-textA" id="frac">
      Fraction</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="aalt" value="'aalt'" class="ot-textA" id="aalt">
      Alternatives</label>
    <br>
        <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="onum" value="'onum'" class="ot-textA" id="onum">
      Oldstyle Numbers</label>
  </p>
</div>
<div id="textA" contenteditable="true"><span>Trying out checkboxes 3/4 </span></div>
```

Comment: For starters there is no such thing has `.css()` on vanilla js. You might want to use `.style` or get the element using jquery instead.

Comment: Thank you, I'll start to work on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some changes to your example code.

- Removed the quotes from the checkbox values
- Added a single change listener to the container element for the checkboxes instead of a listener per checkbox.
- Since "liga" should alway be present I've used this as the initial item in the array you were constructing with selected features. This removes the need to check if there are features selected and just assign the liga feature.

I wasn't sure how comfortable you are with using the ES6 features so I coded the example to somewhat match your style. There are certainly some things which could be further optimised or done in a different way.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var checkboxContainer = document.getElementById('ot-checkboxes');
  
  if (checkboxContainer !== null) {
    // There is no need to wrap the event listener in another method first.
    checkboxContainer.addEventListener('change', getOTFeaturesTextA);
  }
});

function getOTFeaturesTextA(){
  var 
    textA = document.getElementById("textA"),
    selectedFeatures = document.querySelectorAll('.ot-textA:checked');
    // The liga feature should always be present. All feature names should be
    // wrapped in quotes.
    features = ['"liga"'];

  selectedFeatures.forEach(function(selectedFeature) {
    features.push('"' + selectedFeature.value + '"');
  });

  // Set the style by joining all the items in the array with a
  // comma as separator.
  textA.style.fontFeatureSettings = features.join(','); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ot-checkboxes">
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frac" value="frac" class="ot-textA" id="frac">
      Fraction</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="aalt" value="aalt" class="ot-textA" id="aalt">
      Alternatives</label>
    <br>
        <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="onum" value="onum" class="ot-textA" id="onum">
      Oldstyle Numbers</label>
  </p>
</div>
<div id="textA" contenteditable="true"><span>Trying out checkboxes 3/4 </span></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This allows it to work correctly. And thank you for the comments, it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Use style instead of css in this use case

```
textA.style['font-feature-settings'] = selected + ", liga";
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters there is no such thing has `.css()` on vanilla js. You might want to use `.style` or get the element using jquery instead.

```
function getOTFeaturesTextA(){
    const textA = $("#textA");
    const chkArray = [];

    $(".ot-textA:checked").each(function() {
        chkArray.push($(this).val());
    });

    const selected = chkArray.join(',');

    if(selected.length > 0){
        textA.css("font-feature-settings", selected + ", liga");    
    }else{
        textA.css("font-feature-settings", "liga");
    }
}
```

Notes: Avoid `var` and as much as possible do not declare variables in one line. No need to declare an empty variable if you're going to use it immediately after the next line anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, I will go through and apply your notes.